# Is there a website which will let me pull my 3 bureau FICO and not make me sign up for some subscription?

Tags: united-states, credit-score

I've read 3 or 4 other posts on here about free credit reports and scores. What I'd like to know is if there's a way for me to get my 3 bureau FICO without having to do some ballet to get a subscription cancelled.  I've gone through that sort of thing before and they deliberately make it a HUGE pain in the neck to cancel the thing.

I'm fine with paying for that privilege -- time is money man. I'd happily pay an extra $10 just to get my 3 scores and not have to go through the cancel-dance.

Suggestions? My mortgage broker can pull this for $20-25 but it'll give me a ding (even a small one might matter right now).

Answer (score 3):

Equifax has a [Single Use](http://www.equifax.com/compare-products/reports) offering for $20 for their own score or $30 for the three big guy's reports.

I am a fan of [Credit Karma](http://www.creditkarma.com) which offers a free service that reflects the FICO score as good as any you'd pay for. Since each reporting agency can vary slightly, Credit Karma will have a score that's in the same range. And it's pretty much real time.

Comment: Right on, will check those out.

Comment: CRAP. I just paid $30 for a 3 bureau report at Equifax (thought it said score!) and now I have to "upgrade" to get my scores. ARGH.

Comment: OK well I had to call in and get it refunded. Total cost for 3 reports + 3 scores was $39.95. Not great, but not bad. I wonder if avoiding the ding to my report is really worth it.

Comment: Sorry for that. The FICO score was checked only for the Equifax $20 deal. Gotta read things over twice. As far as the ding, you said the broker would charge $20-25, plus the ding. I think you did the right thing.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer: not at all your fault. Just another example of why I dislike credit bureaus. I had to tell the CSR 3 times that I did not want a monitoring sub.

Comment: Much appreciated, jc, may I now have my "answer accepted"? :)

Comment: @jcollum: assuming you're applying for a mortgage, the ding *could* set you back more than $20 over the mid-/long-term. I think you made a good investment.

Comment: @bstpierre my mortgage broker told me that successive pulls don't matter as they are related to the same line of credit; 20 pulls for one line, fine, 20 pulls for 20 lines, bad. Plus, you're assuming that a single pull (or 5 even) has a negative effect. We don't know what the threshold is for pulls changing credit score.

Answer (score 2):

The Government sponsored website will give you one free report from each of the 3 bureaus every year.

No subscription or anything of the sort and no ding (that I've seen).

Most people check it 3 times, every 4 months.

http://www.ftc.gov/bcp/edu/pubs/consumer/credit/cre34.shtm

Comment: A credit report isn't the same thing as a FICO score.  But your certainly could argue that it is more important.

Answer (score 1):

One reason why keep my DCU account active.  Free fico credit scores!

https://www.dcu.org/electronic_services/index.html

but specifically this page
https://www.dcu.org/electronic_services/FICO.html

> By signing up to receive your FREE credit score in PC Branch you'll be
>   able to monitor your credit score, receive two reasons why your credit
>   score is not higher, and learn how to take positive steps towards
>   improving your score. Other services such as this may cost you more
>   than $165* annually. Through DCU you can receive your Equifax FICO
>   Credit Score via PC Branch under Account Manager in your Inbox once a
>   month FREE as part of your Checking Plus or Relationship Checking
>   benefits.
>
> ...

Digital Credit Union

Comment: What is a DCU account? Is that a credit union?